# How to use a class method within an instance method?

Tags: python, class

I have the following example `class`, which has an instance method and two class methods. Of course I know that in this example a class would not really be needed (could be done in a module with functions and variables), but I made this example up to understand the general concept of what I want to do.

I just want to update a class variable from an instance method. The idea would be that `Processed` would have a bunch of instances and then at some point down the line, I would come back and access the `records` and `current_id` objects.

Is this an acceptable way (using a class) to achieve what I want above? Or am I accessing the class methods incorrectly? Should I just access directly using self? Or something else.

To reiterate, I am not asking about other ways to achieve this that do not involve a class.

```
import pandas as pd

class Processed:
    records = []
    current_id = None

    def __init__(self, region: str, current_date: pd.Timestamp):
        self.region = region
        self.current_date = current_date
        
    def update_records(self, country: str) -> None:
        record = {'ID': self.set_id(),
                  'MONTH': self.current_date,
                  'REGION': self.region,
                  'COUNTRY': country}
        self.append_record(record=record)
        
    @classmethod
    def append_record(cls, record: dict) -> None:
        cls.records.append(record)
        
    @classmethod
    def set_id(cls) -> int:
        if cls.current_id is None:
            cls.current_id = 0
        cls.current_id += 1
        return cls.current_id
```

Comment: Documentation says "A class method can be called either on the class or on an instance".

Comment: so that would be either Processed.append_record() or self.append_record(), is that what you are saying? No one is generally preferred over the other? @YuriGinsburg

Comment: `self` is preferred, in case you ever create a class that inherits from this one.

Comment: @JohnGordon is it logical to have `append_record` and `set_id` be class methods or should I just have that code in the `update_records` function and access `records` and `current_id` directly using self?

Comment: I think either way you're suggesting is fine. But do take note of the "Single Responsibility Principle", as well as how the code that uses the class will be interacting with it. In that sense, it could make sense to keep it as it is, especially if you intend to run the `classmethod` without instantiating a new class - meaning, you'd `append` a record, or `set and id` despite not having a new `Processed` class created.